# How to import Gradle/Java8 projects in Eclipse Mars (unsupported class version error)?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-8

I'd like to import Java8 projects to my workspace. When I import them, I receive the following error message:

```
Loading Gradle project preview failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-rc-1-bin.zip'.

Build file '/home/PROJECT/git/PROJECT/libraries/build.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'libraries'.
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/PROJECT/gradle/versioning/VersioningPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
com/PROJECT/gradle/versioning/VersioningPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I set the Java compliance level to `1.8`:

[image]

But still I get this error. My installed Java version is (`java -version`):

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

In my opinion everything is as it should be,... So what's wrong?

EDIT:

My execution environment has the Java8-Version:

[image]

All build path variables point at Java8:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're running Java 8 at Project Properties > Java Build Path > Tab Libraries. Check also your run configuration (Menu Run > Run Configurations > Tab Settings > Execution Environment)

Comment: I updated my question; but I can't change the settings of projects that are not imported yet. Anyway, the default is Java8. My run configuration does no have a tab `settings`.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281466/eclipse-gradle-plugin-could-not-fetch-model-of-type

Comment: I thought that im Mars the Gradle Support is integrated,... For some projects it works without additional installation of plugins,...

Comment: How are you importing your project? If you import as a Gradle Project you can specify the Java home directory.