# Gradle project import fails in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to import existing project to eclipse. I am using eclipse neon and gradle 4.2

I get the following error

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:50)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(DefaultToolingClient.java:88)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultModelRequest.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRequest.java:79)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository$13.get(DefaultModelRepository.java:287)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRepository.java:355)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.access$100(DefaultModelRepository.java:49)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository$14.call(DefaultModelRepository.java:313)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.getFromCache(DefaultModelRepository.java:330)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeRequest(DefaultModelRepository.java:309)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeRequest(DefaultModelRepository.java:280)
at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.fetchGradleBuild(DefaultModelRepository.java:143)
at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchGradleBuild(DefaultModelProvider.java:56)
at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.fetchGradleBuildStructure(ProjectPreviewJob.java:86)
at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(ProjectPreviewJob.java:75)
at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:79)
at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: VM option 'GuaranteedSafepointInterval' is diagnostic and must be enabled via -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions.

```
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:152)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:135)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:204)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:128)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:138)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:143)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:118)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.getModel(DefaultConnection.java:192)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.produceModel(CancellableModelBuilderBackedModelProducer.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.produceModel(PluginClasspathInjectionSupportedCheckModelProducer.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder$1.run(DefaultModelBuilder.java:60)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any way to resolve this error?

Comment: Please look into following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281466/eclipse-gradle-plugin-could-not-fetch-model-of-type