# Spring STS 4.13 not loading gradle 2.14 projects and showing org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException:

Tags: macos-monterey, sts

I have recently upgraded my mac to os monetery and after wards when i try to download sts and try to import gradle projects i keep getting
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException:

I have tried following

1. configure my work space settings to use java 8 and gradle 2.14 by setting up gradle home and java home explicitly on sts
2. overriding the sts setting by specifying javahome and gradle home

I am getting the preview failed exception and not able to set up environment
[Issue screen on sts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04oSO.png)

I tried following steps from here [Eclipse Gradle Plugin 'could not fetch model of type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281466/eclipse-gradle-plugin-could-not-fetch-model-of-type) but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with justj open JDK installation, which was by default coming with springsts4.13.

I had uninstalled openjdk17, which was by default coming with this version, and installed justj openjdk 11.

```
diff -w /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini_bkp
10c10
< ../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.macosx.x86_64_11.0.13.v20211116-1829/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
---
> ../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.macosx.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/lib/libjli.dylib
```